# Python record new hotkey in runtime

Tags: python, keyboard, hotkeys

I am using Windows, and installing new libs is not a problem.
i use the Python keyboard library to handle hotkey presses and the functions connected to them.
To bind a hotkey, i use e.g. `keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+shift+e",print,args=["Hotkey was pressed!"])`

To register that combination, i need the string "ctrl+shift+e". I would like a possibility to *record* a new combination at runtime, that can then be bound to a function. I need this for a settings-window, so the user can configure individual settings with just pressing the sample combination.

What i want to do (simplified example):

```
import keyboard, time

time.sleep(5)
key_combination = read_currently_pressed_combination()
keyboard.add_hotkey(key_combination, print, args=["Hotkey %s was pressed!" % key_combination ])
keyboard.wait()
```

This code is obviously missing the whole recording part. `keyboard.record` does not fit my needs as it just gives a replayable version of the recording, but not the actual string of the combination (as far as i know).
Is this possible with keyboard or msvcrt or any other library there is for keyboard things? I'd be glad about a solution for this. Tried figuring it out myself, but could not find any information on this.
Edit: I do not mind opening an additional window for the recording of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, never mind. Found an undocumented solution to this by digging deep into the source code of the keyboard lib. `keyboard.get_hotkey_name()` is exactly what I needed. Therefore this question is solved.